# How to pass multiple parameters to child component from parent component during on-click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I send multiple parameters to the component during onClick. I have mentioned the code below, its working when I pass single parameter, but it's not working when I tried to pass multiple parameters. So how can I change my on click function to make it work for multiple parameters.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

**Code tested for passing multiple parameters(not working)**

```
<save-job-step cssClass="fa fa-save" v-bind:onClick="saveHazard" 
:id="hazard.id" :detail="hazard.detail" :consequence="hazard.consequence" 
class="save-job-step-icon">
</save-job-step>

let saveComponent = Vue.component('save-component', {
props: {
    label: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    id: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    detail: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    consequence: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    cssClass: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    onClick: Function,
    setStyle: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }
},
template: `<i :class="cssClass" @click="onClick(id,detail,consequence)"></i>`,
```

});

**Working Code for single parameter:**
  **Component 1**

```
<save-job-step cssClass="fa fa-save" v-bind:onClick="saveHazard" 
:id="pHazard.id" class="save-job-step-icon">
</save-job-step>

methods: {
  saveHazard: function (id) {
            alert(currentHazardId);
        }
},
```

**Component 2**

```
let saveComponent = Vue.component('save-component', {
props: {
    label: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    id: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    cssClass: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    onClick: Function,
    setStyle: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }
},
template: `<i :class="cssClass" @click="onClick(id)"></i>`,
```

});

Comment: where is the code for saveHazard function with multiple parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a callback function and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is one approach:

```js
Vue.component('save-component', {
  props: ['id', 'label', 'detail', 'consequence', 'callback'],
  methods: {
    someAction(...args) {
      this.callback.apply(null, args)
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
  <v-btn @click="() => callback.apply(null, [id, label, detail, consequence])" color="indigo" dark>Click Me</v-btn>
  </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      id: 1,
      label: 'foo',
      detail: 'bar',
      consequence: 'baz',
      callback: (...args) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(args))
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <v-layout>
          <save-component :id="id" :label="label" :detail="detail" :consequence="consequence" :callback="callback"></save-component>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```